# Importing changes to Child Theme

Tags: css, child-theme

I've made numerous changes to my theme via the CSS block in Theme Options. Wondering if there's a seamless method to migrate these changes to a Child Theme. I don't have much coding knowledge but I suspect there must be a way to grab a version of the blog as it is (modified) and save that as the child theme. Maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Many good text editors have a "Compare Files" funciton, so use that to compare an unedited copy of the css file and your edited copy and save the differences for your child theme.

Comment: Thank you. Can you suggest one?

Comment: Windows or OS X?

Comment: Windows. Maybe there's a firefox add-on or plugin?

Comment: Use [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/), it doesn't matter which editor you use then. Just be sure to have backups of both the original and your customised version :)